# Implicit vector multiplication

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am reading a book on quantum mechanics, and it heavily involves vectors and matrices. This is more an issue of notation, but what would this be a dot product or a cross product? [image: notation]

Comment: It's matrix multiplication (I guess it can be thought of as dot product between a row and a column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dot product between vectors $u$ and $v$ of dimension $n$ can be viewed as the following matrix product :

$$
\langle u | v \rangle = \begin{pmatrix}u_1 & \dots & u_n\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_n\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since vectors can be viewed as column matrix, this can be also written
$$
\langle u | v \rangle = u^\top v
$$

So in physics, the bra-ket notation is often use, where the row-matrix of vector $u$ is written $\langle u |$ rather than $u^\top$ and the column matrix of $v$ is written $|v\rangle$.

So, $R$ being a $n\times n$ matrix, the notation $\langle u | R | v \rangle$ is simply:

$$
\langle u | R | v \rangle = u^\top R v
$$

using the standard matrix products.